# Display images from array in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I need create a load-on-demand image gallery, and I start from a JSON that defines all the images in the gallery in a format like:

```
var GALLERY_JSON = {
   "size" : "200x200",
   "images": [ 
      {
         "src" : "http://aws.netclime.net/Images/1.png",
         "text" : "This is an image1",
         "link" : "http://cnn.com"
      },
      {
         "src" : "http://aws.netclime.net/Images/2.png",
         "text" : "This is an image2",
         "link" : "http://google.com"            
      },
      …,
      {
         "src" : "http://aws.netclime.net/Images/3.png",
         "text" : "This is an imageN",
         "link" : "http://yahoo.com"            
      }
   ]
};
```

I tried this:

```
function getArticleImage() {
    var image = new Image;
    image.className = 'banner-img';
    image.src = 'aws.netclime.net/Images/1.png';
    image.setAttribute("height", "200px");
    image.setAttribute("width", "200px");
    image.onload = function() {
        image.classList.remove();
    };
    return image;
}
```

I need an advice, which is the proper way to display those images with text and link in HTML?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some basic research in to HTML and JavaScript ;)

Comment: This is quite unclear. How should the result look? What does the desired HTML structure look like? Is the `text` the title of the link, an image description, the value for the `alt`-attribute? Have you tried anything already?

Comment: The result should be a page with loaded images. I try this: 'function getArticleImage() {
    var image = new Image;
    image.className = 'banner-img';
    image.src = 'http://aws.netclime.net/Images/1.png';
    image.setAttribute("height", "200px");
    image.setAttribute("width", "200px");
    image.onload = function() {
        image.classList.remove();
    };

    return image;
}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This should get you started...

```js
var GALLERY_JSON = {
   "size" : "200x200",
   "images": [ 
      {
         "src" : "http://aws.netclime.net/Images/1.png",
         "text" : "This is an image1",
         "link" : "http://cnn.com"
      },
      {
         "src" : "http://aws.netclime.net/Images/2.png",
         "text" : "This is an image2",
         "link" : "http://google.com"            
      },
      {
         "src" : "http://aws.netclime.net/Images/3.png",
         "text" : "This is an imageN",
         "link" : "http://yahoo.com"            
      }
   ]
};

function getArticleImage(data) {
    var image = new Image;
    image.className = 'banner-img';
    image.src = data.src;
    image.setAttribute("height", data.height);
    image.setAttribute("width", data.width);
    image.onload = function() {
      image.classList.remove();
    };
    return image;
}

GALLERY_JSON.images.forEach(function(data){
  data.width = GALLERY_JSON.size.match(/^[0-9]+/);
  data.height = GALLERY_JSON.size.match(/[0-9]+$/);
  document.body.appendChild( getArticleImage(data) );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop over your array, create a link element containing an image and append it to the DOM. Here are two links providing documentation and examples :

- [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Answer (score 0):

**I would recommend templating.**

IMHO it's a much more powerful solution, you can easily change the template to embed your data in any third party gallery/carousel you want and it's more legible.

**Example**

Here is an example with the template embeded in the HTML (you could have it out there for better organization)

It relies on

- MustacheJS for the templating
- JQuery just for getting divs by id (you could easily remove that JQuery dependency with DOM if you don't need JQuery anywhere else)

The *hacky .match()* part is to extract the width and height, if you could provide those 2 values as variables at GALLERY_JSON you wouldn't need that.

```js
var GALLERY_JSON = {
   "size" : "200x200",
   "images": [ 
      {
         "src" : "http://aws.netclime.net/Images/1.png",
         "text" : "This is an image1",
         "link" : "http://cnn.com"
      },
      {
         "src" : "http://aws.netclime.net/Images/2.png",
         "text" : "This is an image2",
         "link" : "http://google.com"            
      },
      {
         "src" : "http://aws.netclime.net/Images/3.png",
         "text" : "This is an imageN",
         "link" : "http://yahoo.com"            
      }
   ]
};

var width = GALLERY_JSON.size.match(/^[0-9]+/);
var height = GALLERY_JSON.size.match(/[0-9]+$/);

GALLERY_JSON.width = width;
GALLERY_JSON.height = height;

var template = $('#template').html();
var gallery = Mustache.render(template, GALLERY_JSON);
$('#gallery').html(gallery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.2.1/mustache.min.js"></script>

<div id="gallery"></div>

<script id="template" type="template/mustache">
<ul>
  {{#images}}
  <li>
    <a href="{{link}}">
      <img src="{{src}}" alt="{{text}}" height="{{height}}" width="{{width}}">
      <p>{{text}}</p>
  </a>
  </li>
  {{/images}}
</ul>
</script>
```